# Populating Dropdownlist from List collection c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

***I have a class named memberdetails and memberdb which are part of my class library. I am using asp.net C# with MSSQL as the back end***

My memberdetails class

```
     public int MemID
     {
        get { return memID; }      
     }

     public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

     public MemberDetails(int memID, string firstName)
        {
        this.memID = memID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        }
```

memberdb class

```
public List<MemberDetails> MemberResult(int memid)
    {  
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))         
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            List<MemberDetails> memberdetails = new List<MemberDetails>();
            MemberDetails member;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "usp_Member_Result";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memgen", memid);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        member = new MemberDetails((int)reader["memid"],  (string)reader["firstname"]);
                        memberdetails.Add(member);

                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    return memberdetails;                          
                 }
            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error.", err);
            }
            finally
            {            
                if (con != null)
                    con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

***After I compile those classes into a DLL and then add it as a reference to my project I am trying to bind my DropDownlist to retrieve those values. In the codebehind page I am getting a value from the gridview putting it into a variable "memgen" sending that to my method and then returning the results. When I debug my application I see the values are returned however they are not binded to the DropDownList.***

CodeBehind Page

```
 member.MemberResult(memgen);
   // MemberDetails details = new MemberDetails();

    ddlFamilyMembers.DataTextField = "Text";
    ddlFamilyMembers.DataValueField = "Value"; 
  //  ddlFamilyMembers.DataSource = memberdetails; << "This does not exist in the current context"
    ddlFamilyMembers.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code-behind needs to change to be something like this:

```
List<MemberDetails> details = member.MemberResult(memgen); 

ddlFamilyMembers.DataTextField = "FirstName"; 
ddlFamilyMembers.DataValueField = "MemID";  
ddlFamilyMembers.DataSource = details;
ddlFamilyMembers.DataBind();
```

The specific changes:

1. Capture the result of `MemberResult`
2. Use the correct field names for `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`
3. Set the `DataSource` property

Comment: That worked but why do you have to create the list twice? Do you mind giving a small explanation so I can try and understand. I thought since I was returning memberdetails in my class I would be able to reference that as my datasource

Comment: I'll do my best.  You were indeed returning `memberdetails` in your class.  But because you weren't assigning the result of the call to the `MemberResult` method to anything, that value was getting lost and being discarded.  You had to declare a variable of type List<MemberDetails> to receive it.  The DataSource property was then set to that new variable `details`.

Comment: You could also have used the line `ddlMembers.DataSource = member.MemberResult(memgen);` if you don't want to use a variable to receive the results of `member.MemberResult`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your answer. Really appreciate it, I understand now what I was doing wrong. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you forgot to add the datasource of the dropdownlist.

You can do as shown below :

```
var ddlvals = member.MemberResult(memgen); 

ddlFamilyMembers.DataTextField = "FirstName"; 
ddlFamilyMembers.DataValueField = "MemID";  
ddlFamilyMembers.DataSource = ddlvals;
ddlFamilyMembers.DataBind();
```

Without binding that won't work. I hope this helps your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MemberDetails> details = member.MemberResult(memgen); 

ddlFamilyMembers.DataTextField = "FirstName"; 
ddlFamilyMembers.DataValueField = "MemID";  
ddlFamilyMembers.DataSource = details;
ddlFamilyMembers.DataBind();
```